# In Pasting Lemma, why do sets $X$, $Y$ have to be both closed (or both open)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma

I am trying to understand the proof of the Pasting Lemma as shown in the WikiPedia link above.

So far, I understand it except two questions that I have:

Q1) I don't see where the fact that $X$, $Y$ are both closed is being used?

Q2) When they say $f^{-1}(U)\cap X$ is closed, do they mean closed in $A$ or closed in $X$?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I suppose that you are familiar with the following definition of continuity: A function from a topological space $ X $ to another $ Y $ is continuous if and only if the pre-image of every closed subset of $ Y $ is a closed subset of $ X $.

Comment: The fact that they are closed is used essentially to render sterile the question "where are they closed".

Comment: @Transcendental Yes indeed I am familiar with that.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Thanks. You mean it is not a necessary requirement? $X$, $Y$ need not be both closed (or both open)?

Comment: @yoyostein They need, exactly to make your question 2 be a non-issue. So your question 2 responds, in some sense, your question 1. Because the hypothesis gives that the set in your question 2 is closed * on the subspace*, but since the subspace is closed * on the space*, the set is also closed on the space

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: Counter-example when  $ X, Y $  are not both open or both closed:  $ A=B=\mathbb R, $... $ X=(-\infty , 0), $....$ Y=[0,\infty). $  Then  $ X $ \ $ Y \subset$ int $(X) $  and $ Y $ \ $ X \subset$  int $(Y) $  because $ X $ \ $ Y=Y $  \ $ X=\emptyset.  $ Let  $ f_1(p)=0 $ for   $ p\in X. $ Let $ f_2(q)=1 $ for $ q\in Y. $ Then $ f_1\cup f_2 $ is not continuous.